# inline-block anchor tags out of place can someone tell me why?

Tags: html, css

building a new site, and working on a news ticker, it has hash marks below it for navigation.  The hash marks reside in an absolute div at the bottom of the ticker module.  Inside the div are the anchor tags and some spacers, they are renderring below where they should and I cant seem to identify why, can someone take a look and help me out?

http://race.3drexstaging.com/Home  is the link.

Thanks for any help

HTML

```
<div class="dnnForm Normal NewsFeedHolder">
    <div class="newsFeedInner">

                <div class="feedItems" id="newsItem0">
                    <span class="feedTitles">Featured Promotions : </span>
                    <span class="feedTexts">Example - 50% OFF SALE! On Select Products and Services</span>
                </div>

                <div class="feedItems inactive active" id="newsItem1">
                    <span class="feedTitles">Another Headline : </span>
                    <span class="feedTexts">You can put info about another sale here</span>
                </div>

                <div class="feedItems inactive" id="newsItem2">
                    <span class="feedTitles">Yet Another Headline : </span>
                    <span class="feedTexts">More information about your sale</span>
                </div>

    </div>
    <div class="newsFeedNavs">
        <div class="newsFeedNavsInner">

                    <a class="newsNavItems" id="newsNavItem0" href="javascript:getNewsItem(0)"></a>

                    <span class="newsSpacer"></span>

                    <a class="newsNavItems inactive active" id="newsNavItem1" href="javascript:getNewsItem(1)"></a>

                    <span class="newsSpacer"></span>

                    <a class="newsNavItems inactive" id="newsNavItem2" href="javascript:getNewsItem(2)"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CURRENT CSS:

```
.feedItems
{
    color: white;
}
.feedTitles
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ce0d25;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.feedTexts
{

}
.NewsFeedHolder
{
   position: relative;
}
.newsFeedInner
{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.newsFeedNavs
{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.newsFeedNavsInner {
    height: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.newsNavItems
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
    a.newsNavItems:hover, a.newsNavItems.active
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
.feedItems
{
    display: none;
}
    .feedItems.active
    {
        display: block;
    }
.newsSpacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    line-height: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post relevent CSS and html here?  Also, could you elaborate where exactly you want the anchor tags and spacers to appear?  when you say 'below where they should' by how much?

Comment: Sorry, they should appear inline with the red line, not below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
.newsFeedNavsInner {
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.newsNavItems {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 2px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

or

[image]

```
.newsFeedNavsInner {
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.newsNavItems {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.newsSpacer {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  line-height: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation goes a long way.

Comment: well, this works, and I will go with it because it does not make a difference to me whether I use inline or floated elements.

Comment: I just set it like every list elements to float left, add a little margins and change padding on `.newsFeedNavsInner`.

Comment: Fair enough. But check out where your spacers end up (I gave them blue borders): http://jsfiddle.net/wxMB8/ Probably should be floating them, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align` of your container is set to `baseline` (default.css line 39).

I suggest setting it to `top`:

```
div.newsFeedNavsInner {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

### EDIT:

Given your newly posted code, set it on each nav item:

```
.newsNavItems {
    ....
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrjwU/

Comment: That did not fix it, the height of that parent div is set to 2, so I would expect that the vertical alignment would not effect it anyways.